# getting a stack overflow in Clojure function.

Tags: recursion, clojure

Why am I getting a stack overflow in the following Clojure function:

```
(defn length
  [xs]
  (if ,(not= xs nil)
    (println (+ 1 (length (rest xs))))
    (println 0)))
```

Comment: You don't talk about stack overflow on StackOverflow. lol

Comment: <insert witty statement about site/question recursion here>

Comment: Not knowing clojure, but will "rest xs" return nil when xs has only 1 element? or will it return an empty list/string/whatever that isn't nil?

Comment: I assume the stack is just overflowing for the expected reasion.  Clojure does not automatically optimize tail calls (and although this is not a tail call, it could be trivially be rewritten to be one).

Comment: I also find it hard to believe that this is the best way to implement a length function in a functional language, it looks horribly non-performant to me.

Comment: What does the comma in front of (not= denote?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the idiomatic way of doing this is to call `seq` on your collection.  `seq` on a collection returns `nil` if the collection is empty.

```
(defn length [xs]
  (if (seq xs)
      (inc (length (rest xs)))
      0))
```

This isn't tail-recursive (you aren't using `recur` and can't here) so this will still overflow the stack on very large collections.

```
user> (println (length (range 1000000)))
;; stack overflow
```

One tail-recursive version would be

```
(defn length [xs]
  (loop [xs xs
         acc 0]
    (if (seq xs)
        (recur (rest xs) (inc acc))
        acc)))

user> (println (length (range 1000000)))
1000000
```

This won't overflow the stack even for huge collections but it's still slow.  Many Clojure collections implement the `Counted` interface and the built-in `count` function returns the length of those collections in constant time.

Answer (score 4):

After the switch to all lazy seqs, rest will never return nil, just an empty list - try this:

```
(defn length 
   [xs]
   (if (not (empty? xs))
      (println (+ 1 (length (rest xs))))
      (println 0)))
```

OR this

```
(defn length
   [xs]
   (if ,(not= xs nil)
      (println (+ 1 (length (next xs))))
      (println 0)))
```